# What does STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION from a samba share really mean, and could it result in no files being present at all?

Tags: samba, smb

I have an issue writing files to a samba share. We don't seem to receive any failure error during the writing of the files, but a second later when we check from a different process, no files have been written. This problem seems to happen sporadically for about 5 minutes, or 10 minutes, and then go away.

The only clue we have is from the samba's logging. There are STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION errors present. My understanding is that this means our software is trying to write a new file over a file that already exists. But what I don't understand is why, then, I see no files in that location at all after the process concludes. Could this error mean something else? Could it be caused by the configuration of the fileshare somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION may indicate an attempt to create a file which already exists while overwrite option was not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Is your soft renaming any file on the destination?

Comment: I'm not sure what this is. I googled and couldnt find any documentation. What does this refer to?